# How to cancel event updatedAt in mongooes

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm new in mongo and nodejs.

I'm doing a project, in a table, I use createdAt and updatedAt to auto create/update time of a document

```
let User = new Schema(
    {
        "_id": String,
        "name": String,
    }, {
        timestamps: {
            createdAt: "created_time",
            updatedAt: "updated_time"
        }
    }
```

It work fine when I create and update User. But now I need to update a field (ex: User.name) with the updated_time not changes. Can I do that?

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({"_id": user_id}, {"name": "some value"});
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you explain what actually goes wrong along with an example of expected outcome

Comment: @sam My sample code is fine, when create document, new document have new Date() in created_time and updated_time. When update, field updated_time get the new Date() too. Then I have a request to update a field but not change the updated_time. Ex: A document have name is 'viet long tran' and updated_time is 2020-09-06 14:00:00.000. Change name to 'viet long tran 1', but updated_time not allow to change, still keep value 2020-09-06 14:00:00.000.

Comment: Did you actually try running that `findOneAndUpdate` command?  If so, did it not work the way you expected?  Showing us the output you expected vs. the output you got will help us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set timestamps option to false

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({"_id": user_id}, {"name": "some value"}, {timestamps: false});
```

I tried on my local machine -

Before update -

```
> db.users.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f54b60f8da3e24452f535c9"), "name" : "Sid", "created_time" : ISODate("2020-09-06T10:12:31.769Z"), "updated_time" : ISODate("2020-09-06T10:12:31.769Z"), "__v" : 0 }
```

After Update-

```
> db.users.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f54b60f8da3e24452f535c9"), "name" : "Sid_Updated", "created_time" : ISODate("2020-09-06T10:12:31.769Z"), "updated_time" : ISODate("2020-09-06T10:12:31.769Z"), "__v" : 0 }
```

Comment: I try your solution but Updated_time still get the new value when document update.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the syntax correctly? I tried it on local and it works for me.
Edited answer with my test.

Comment: Yeah I try at the sample code then it's work correctly. But don't know why when I add to main project it not working :(. Thanks for your answer, I will examine it more closely